# SQL QUERY: return the values1 which have the same value2 in other column, only if the values1 are different

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to query a database in order to get the different values which point to the same values in other column. For example:

Table1:

```
Letter     :    Number
a ---------------1
b ---------------1
b ---------------2
a ---------------1
a ---------------3
a ---------------3
c ---------------5
```

Expected output:

```
a ---------------1
b ---------------1
a ---------------1
```

Unfortunately, I don't use RDBMS that supports window functions.

Comment: And why not c/5?  I can't figure out the logic you really want.

Comment: How does the data magically transform from Table1 to Expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`:

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.number = t.number and t1.letter != t.letter
)
```

On a RDBMS that supports window functions, you can also do a window `count(distinct)`:

```
select t.number, t.letter
from (
    select 
        t.number, 
        t.letter,
        count(distinct t.letter) over(partition by t.letter) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: The first query doesn't have a condition for the column "Letter" to have at least 2 same values.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( Letter CHAR(1), number INT );

INSERT INTO table1 ( Letter, number )
SELECT 'a', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 5
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   table1 x
  WHERE  x.number = t.number
  GROUP BY number
  HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT Letter ) > 1
)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> Letter | number
> :----- | -----:
> a      |      1
> b      |      1
> a      |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d9ee3a6a0098cdac32aeb06d2fa079af)*

---

You can do it in a single table-scan using the `COUNT` analytic function:

**Oracle Setup**

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( Letter, "NUMBER" ) AS
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 5 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT Letter, "NUMBER"
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( DISTINCT Letter ) OVER ( PARTITION BY "NUMBER" ) AS num_letters
  FROM   table1 t
)
WHERE  num_letters > 1
```

**Output**:

> ```
> LETTER | NUMBER
> :----- | -----:
> a      |      1
> a      |      1
> b      |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=375e307bcf275e44262039019f8a347c)*

Comment: And exactly how is using a window function "a single scan"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=36820129fc6d19d28bde6c0fbadba7a0) The explain plan there shows you that the table is read only once.

Comment: Window Sort  is not exactly cheap.  It is doing a lot of work . . . probably reading the table again (but from an intermediate result).

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use RDBMS that supports window functions.

Comment: @Maria1995 You tagged Oracle in your question; this is for Oracle RDBMS (not Oracle Corporation). If this was mistaken then you should remove this tag from the question.

Comment: @Maria1995 Updated with a MySQL solution.